# How to call URL action in MVC with javascript function?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I´m trying to render url action with javascript in an MVC project.  I capture an event on my page which calls this function but I´m not sure how to call this certain URL.

Can anyone help me please?  :)

```
function onDropDownChange(e) {
    var url = '/Home/Index/' + e.value;
    //What now...?
}
```

-----------Edited-----------------------

Here´s my controller action:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        var tmpToday = DateTime.Now;
        var today = new DateTime(tmpToday.Year, tmpToday.Month, tmpToday.Day, 0, 0, 0);

        if (id != null)
        {
            var num = id.GetValueOrDefault();
            var rentableUnits = new List<Unit>();
            _unitLogic.GetAllRentableUnitsByArea(num, rentableUnits);

            var allAvailabilities = new ShowAvailability[rentableUnits.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < rentableUnits.Count; i++)
            {
                var sTime = GetFirstDayOfMonth(today);
                var eTime = GetLastDayOfMonth(today);
                allAvailabilities[i] = new ShowAvailability(sTime, eTime.AddHours(23.0).AddMinutes(59.0), rentableUnits);
                today = today.AddMonths(1);
            }

            var showAvailability = new List<ShowAvailability>(allAvailabilities);

            return View(new HomeFormViewModel(showAvailability));
        }
        else
        {
            var allAvailabilities = new ShowAvailability[12];

            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
                var sTime = GetFirstDayOfMonth(today);
                var eTime = GetLastDayOfMonth(today);
                allAvailabilities[i] = new ShowAvailability(sTime, eTime.AddHours(23.0).AddMinutes(59.0));
                today = today.AddMonths(1);
            }

            var showAvailability = new List<ShowAvailability>(allAvailabilities);

            return View(new HomeFormViewModel(showAvailability));
        }
    }
```

#

I´m using Telerik extension for my DropDownList which fires the javascript function, this is in fact a Razor View:

```
 @(Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
     .Name("DropDownList")
     .Items(area =>
         {
             area.Add().Text("Öll svæði").Value("0").Selected(true);
             foreach (Unit a in Model.Areas)
                {
                     area.Add().Text(a.Name).Value(a.UnitID.ToString());
                }
         })
     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 130px;" })
     .ClientEvents(clev => clev.OnChange("onDropDownChange"))
     )
```

Here´s the script:

```
function onDropDownChange(e) {
    var url = '/Home/Index/' + e.value;
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            data: {},
            dataType: "html"
        });
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `onDropDownChange`? What does `e` corresponds to?

Comment: are you looking for ajax call or new page load? have you tried googling for "javascript call new url"?

Comment: What do you mean call? Reload the page to a new one, or obtain the data from that url without refreshing?

Comment: I´m trying a new page load, and the e stands for the id value needed to complete the url, for instance like this:
http://localhost:111/home/index/20

Comment: Basically if I could render this action from javascript:
@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new {id = e.value})
...that would be perfect :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Within your `onDropDownChange` handler, just make a jQuery AJAX call, passing in any data you need to pass up to your URL.  You can handle successful and failure calls with the `success` and `error` options.  In the `success` option, use the data contained in the `data` argument to do whatever rendering you need to do.  Remember these are asynchronous by default!

```
function onDropDownChange(e) {
    var url = '/Home/Index/' + e.value;
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: {}, //parameters go here in object literal form
      type: 'GET',
      datatype: 'json',
      success: function(data) { alert('got here with data'); },
      error: function() { alert('something bad happened'); }
    });
}
```

jQuery's AJAX documentation is [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 13):

I'm going to give you 2 way's to call an action from the client side

**first**

If you just want to navigate to an action you should call just use the follow

```
window.location = "/Home/Index/" + youid
```

**Notes:** that you action need to handle a get type called

**Second**

If you need to render a View you could make the called by ajax

```
//this if you want get the html by get
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    return View(); //this return the render html   
}
```

And the client called like this "Assuming that you're using jquery"

```
$.get('your controller path', parameters to the controler , function callback)
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "your controller path",
    data: parameters to the controler
    dataType: "html",
    success: your function
});
```

or

```
$('your selector').load('your controller path')
```

**Update**

In your ajax called make this change to pass the data to the action

```
function onDropDownChange(e) {
var url = '/Home/Index' 
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: { id = e.value}, <--sending the values to the server
        dataType: "html",
        success : function (data) {
            //put your code here
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

You cannot do this in your callback 'windows.location ' if you want it's go render a view, you need to put a `div` in your view and do something like this

**in the view where you are that have the combo in some place**

```
<div id="theNewView"> </div> <---you're going to load the other view here
```

**in the javascript client**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: { id = e.value}, <--sending the values to the server
        dataType: "html",
        success : function (data) {
            $('div#theNewView').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

With this i think that you solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jorge.  I´ve been trying the $.ajax example you gave me.  I have stepped through my code and everything seems fine until my View() has finished loading, that is, the page doesn´t seem to refresh (maybe I´m using it wrong).  Should I put the full path into the url parameter, like this -->  url: '/Home/Index/' + e.value  or like this  -->  url: '/Home/Index/' with this data: e.value ?

Comment: could you please update your question and show me the controller associated? and how it's your routing...

Comment: Hello again, yes I´ve edited my post.  I hope this makes any sense :/

Comment: Thanx Jorge, this seems to be working fine now, at least mostly  :)   Although my problems aren´t completely over because there seems to be something wrong with my routing, my data seems to go in all the right directions, but my page doesn´t refresh.  When I write the correct url in the web browser then everything shows up correctly, for instance -->  http://localhost/Home/Index/20, but not with the DropDownList, I saw with break-point that the action was called with right parameters, I´m not sure, perhaps I need to check my Global.asax and see if I need to change the url routing in any way?!

Comment: update you question and show me how you're handling the callback of the ajax called first, also check with http://www.charlesproxy.com/ which are error are throwing the server. Instead of modified the routing

Comment: That´s the thing, I´m embarrased to say this but I think I am really misunderstanding the callback because I´ve been doing it like this:  -->  success: function () { window.location.reload( true ); }  <--  when in fact you would really need something like this:  -->  success: function () { callback.loadUrl('/Home/Index/20'); } <--  but I really am not sure how to get to this, or how the correct syntax is.

Comment: Excellent! That did the trick!  You are a life-safer  :)  Thank you for your help, I hope I can return the favor later.

Comment: it should be id : e.value not id = e.value.

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
var url = '/Home/Index/' + e.value;
 window.location = window.location.host + url;
```

That should get you where you want.

Comment: In response to the above posted comments - url = '/home/Index/' + e.value; - what if e.value contains sensitive information that you don't want seen in the url? How do we conceal that?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to ensure you get the correct url regardless of server settings is to put the url into a hidden field on your page and reference it for the path:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="GetIndexDataPath" value="@Url.Action("Index","Home")" />
```

Then you just get the value in your ajax call:

```
var path = $("#GetIndexDataPath").val();
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: path,
        data: { id = e.value},  
        dataType: "html",
        success : function (data) {
            $('div#theNewView').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

I have been using this for years to cope with server weirdness, as it always builds the correct url. It also makes keeping track of changing controller method calls a breeze if you put all the hidden fields together in one part of the html or make a separate razor partial to hold them.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following on the JavaScript side:

```js
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Controller")';
```

If you want to pass parameters to the `@Url.Action`, you can do this:

```js
var reportDate = $("#inputDateId").val();//parameter
var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Controller", new {dateRequested = "findme"})';
window.location.href = url.replace('findme', reportDate);
```